# Polymer hero-transition in custom element

Tags: polymer, transition, shadow-dom

I'm using [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org) for a new version on my website. I'm currently experimenting with the hero-transition of the [`core-animated-pages`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-animated-pages). Some examples are provided [in the `core-animated-pages` examples](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/demo.html) and especially [this one](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/demos/quiz1.html).

With these examples I've got to understand the examples and I've gotten to this example: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/siyawobizemu/1/edit). It's not entirely polished, but it works.

Now, I want to have the card show in this example to be a custom element. Of this custom element I would need the to have two `hero-id`'s, one for the image and one for an album title. I tried simulating it in [this example](http://jsbin.com/hipahehuviru/2/edit). Here's the code:

**album-card custom element**

```
<polymer-element name="album-card">

  <template>
    <style>
      :host{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        background-color: grey;
        width: 200px;
      }
      .description{
        padding: 0px 10px;
        color: white;
      }
      .cube{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
      }
    </style>

    <div vertical layout>
      <div class="cube" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-3.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center center;" hero-id="photo-hero" hero></div>
      <div class="description">
        <content select="h2" hero-id="title-hero" hero></content>
        <content select="h4"></content>
      </div>
    </div>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer("album-card", {});
  </script>

</polymer-element>
```

**The main element with where the transition appears**

```
<polymer-element name="my-app">

  <template>
    <style>
    </style>

    <core-animated-pages selected="{{photopage}}" transitions="hero-transition cross-fade" on-tap="{{albumTapped}}">
      <section>
        <album-card>
          <h2>Album name</h2>
          <h4>x pictures</h4>
        </album-card>
      </section>
      <section>
        <core-toolbar class="tall" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-3.jpg); background-size: cover;background-position: 50% 50%;" hero-id="photo-hero" hero>
          <div class="title bottom" hero hero-id="title-hero">Album name</div>
        </core-toolbar>
      </section>
    </core-animated-pages>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer("my-app", {
      photopage: 0,
      albumTapped: function(){
        this.photopage++;
      }
    });
  </script>

</polymer-element>
```

Now I know this is due to the shadow dom in which the `hero-id` and `hero` attributes of the fields are set, thus not being accessible by other elements on the page, but is there a way around this in this particular case?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not about the shadow dom. the animated goes for hero "1 shadow-dom of depth" and cross-fade any shadow-dom deep.
 The thing is that your custom album-card was getting all "bindy" before ready callback and trampling stuff.
 Also, the way you choose the selected album is kinda messed up (at least that's what i figure) so with your code (<strike>and i gotta leave office **now**</strike> I'm home having fun editing my answer and striking stuff) i made it work <strike>in reverse</strike> back and forth as such: [your fixed code (updated 2)](http://jsbin.com/doyisa/3/edit)

<strike>I'm sorry i wouldn't fiddle more with it because I really gotta leave. Maybe later i'll comeback and explain it better but at least the</strike> "TLDR" answer is here: you shouldn't bind stuff before the ready callback (actually you can but it is specific and should be declared explicitly on the element prototype). <strike>i'll probably get back here later</strike>(here i am). hope it helps. 
**ADDENDUM:** oh and i didn't noticed at the time (i was in a hurry) you were nesting your element in a section, with custom elements, that's not needed (nor expected by the component in this case).

**the full code just for copy/paste easiness:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src='http://www.polymer-project.org/webcomponents.js'></script>
  <link rel='import' href='http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html'>
  <link rel='import' href='http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html'>
  <link rel='import' href='http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html'></head>
<body>
<!-- your album card element -->
  <polymer-element name="album-card" noscript>
    <template>
      <style>
          #thumbAlbum{
            display: block;
            background-color: grey;
            width: 200px;
          }
          #albumDesc{
            padding: 0px 10px;
            color: white;
          }
          #albumCover{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
          }
        </style>

      <div id="thumbAlbum" vertical layout>
        <div id="albumCover" class="cube" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-3.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center center;" hero-id="photo-hero" hero></div>
        <div id="albumDesc" class="description">
          <content select="h2" hero-id="title-hero" hero></content>
          <content select="h4"></content>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </polymer-element>
<!-- your app alement -->
  <polymer-element name="my-app">
    <template>
      <core-animated-pages selected="{{photopage}}" transitions="hero-transition cross-fade" on-tap="{{albumTapped}}">
          <album-card>
            <h2>Album name</h2>
            <h4>x pictures</h4>
          </album-card>
          <section>
          <core-toolbar class="tall" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-3.jpg); background-size: cover;background-position: 50% 50%;" hero-id="photo-hero" hero>
            <div class="title bottom" hero hero-id="title-hero">Album name</div>
          </core-toolbar>
        </section>
      </core-animated-pages>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer("my-app", {
          photopage: 0,
          ready:function(){
          },
          albumTapped: function(){
            this.photopage = this.photopage > 0 ? 0 : 1;
          },
        });
      </script>
  </polymer-element>

  <my-app></my-app>

</body>
</html>
```

**Oh, and on an important sidenote:** always use the webcomponents.js as platform.js is deprecated and not really friendly to find out problems. **plus** import the polymer.html.

Comment: In the mean time I am using the `webcomponents.js`, thanks. Thanks for the update as well. In the fiddle however, the title does not correctly transform - it comes from the top-left corner of the screen instead of the title of the album..

Comment: i will try and fix that. if you figure it out let me know. i'll probably use these transitions later on my project tinkering them makes for a great learning experience.

Comment: done. http://jsbin.com/doyisa/3/edit check it out. the title issue was probably shadow dom depth related as you guessed. the simple work-around is this one i came up with, later i'll try and manage something more definitive.

Comment: @Caio I don't really understand what you mean by "you shouldn't bind stuff before the ready callback (actually you can but it is specific and should be declared explicitly on the element prototype)" - I cannot see any binding in his code in `album-card` nor in `my-app`.

Comment: @PawelZubrycki he has pohotpage binded and albumtap, (maybe more, it's been a couple of days since a last read the full code) both are published. but that's my code, not sure about his, i think he was using unregistered album-card inside the my-app in his code. You see, code order matters. It'll actually give you more trouble on polyfills but natively it's more forgiving.

Comment: note: about your answer; yes, it does, but it will probably break on polyfills, things get more strict. but the main issue was the custom element nested inside a section, why? the docs say you should not. just the way it is. I could dive into the transition code and figure out but i guess someone like eric or dodson or arthur would be better suited AND actually paid for. (while i am paid by  the hour and came over here and spent time just to help. you're welcome)

Comment: sorry i think it came out rude. i'm pissed at other personal stuff, not you, i am sorry if i did. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems to work if you just remove `album-card` element from `section` element: http://jsbin.com/botoxaneju/1/edit?html,output

I am not really sure why is that, because I am experiencing the same problem.